# Could you answer my nooby questions about cpp network programming(more precisely abot asio library)?

Tags: c++, network-programming, asio

For some reasons I made the decision, that network programming will be my favourite programming area. I just have finished with getting started in OP in c++, I don't have any knowledge in network protocols and network programming.
Please, can you explain for me these aspects:

1)What problems the network programmers are solving? (examples whould be awesome)

2)All of the applications, which are using the Internet, somehow are related with the network parogramming, I am right? (examples would be awesome)

3)Is it intersting to work with network programming? Is network programming creative? Are there many useful things which can I do with that?(examples please)

4)How can I get into these area?

P.S
I am asking all of those questions in context of the asio library

P.S.S 
There may be some problems with English, sorry for that. I tried to find some information myself,but I couldnt find any for my specific level of knowledge.

Comment: This question may be suited best elsewhere. Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions. Your question does not seem to focus on programming, but rather networking. Also, you should probably focus on mastering C++ first and then focus on networking.

Comment: @NajmHoda Got that. May be you know some already existing places where I can find useful information? Should I delete this question?

Comment: Don't delete it. You can try to find a networking StackExchange and request for it to be moved there. Edit: check out [this networking StackExchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366257/everything-a-c-developer-should-know-about-network-programming?rq=1) may also answer some of your questions.

Comment: @NajmHoda I tried to post this question in that place. My question was closed because of the off-topic theme(programming is off-topic theme in that place). So I think probably my question should be here